# Storing an array of hashes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to store values in a json column (Postgresql) named `team_setup` with this format:

```
[
 {"user_id" : "value1", "task" : "task1"},
 {"user_id" : "value2", "task" : "task2"}
]
```

This column needs to be filled via a web form. This is what I have so far:

```
simple_form_for :edit_team, url: edit_path do |e_team|
   e_team.simple_fields_for :team_setup do |team_member| %>
     team_member.input :user_id
     team_member.input :task
   end
   e_team.button :submit, 'Add member'
end
```

But well, what I get out of this is

```
 {"user_id" : "value1", "task" : "task1"}
```

There are two issues with this result:

1. The outlined brackets [ ] are missing and
2. with every submit of the formula the previous data in the column is overwritten. But this should only be the case if the `user_id` value already exists - then the task should be saved with a new value. Otherwise the new hash should simply be added.

I've already tried to evoke an array with

```
e_team.simple_fields_for :team_setup, [] do |team_member|
```

But then I got an error

> undefined method `user_id' for []:Array

Comment: Can you post the code for the model you're attempting to implement this for?

Comment: I wish I could, but actually there are no definitions regarding the team_setup  field. When I tried to evoke the array, I added something like: 
_has_one :team_setup_
_accepts_nested_attributes_for :team_setup_

But with this I ran in troubles with my loop over the team_setup column: 
_@edit_idea.team_setup.each do |team|_ 
let me get an error "uninitialized constant Idea::TeamSetup"

Comment: What I meant is you have a model that is supposed to `has_many :team_setups` or something - from your comment it looks like it might be an `Idea` model. That code would live in `app/models/idea.rb`. Can you copy the code from that entire file into your question?